# Do I require a South African transit visa when traveling to Botswana?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, south-africa, algerian-citizens

I'm Algerian citizen, traveling to Gaborone Botswana via Johannesburg (Algiers-Doha- Johannesburg-Gaborone). Do I need South African transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Cape
>   Town (CPT), Durban (DUR), Johannesburg (JNB) or Lanseria (HLA)
>   with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country.

So if Doha-Johannesburg-Gaborone is in a single booking, you do **not** need a visa.